# path finding in prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I need to write a program in prolog for finding paths, for example, for the graph:

```
edge(a, b). 
edge(a, c). 
edge(c, b).
```

and the test case are:

```
/* test case 1 */
?- path(a, b, P). 
P = [a, b] ;
P = [a, c, b] ; 
false. 

/* test case 2 */
?- path(c,b,[c,b]).
true.
```

and my code is

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y]):-
    edge(X,Y).
path(X,Z,[X|P]):-
    edge(X,Y),
    path(Y,Z,P).
```

However, for the test case 2, my code will show

```
?- path(c,b,[c,b]).
true;
false.
```

I know that I should add a cut in my code to remove the false in case 2, but it will remove the false in case 1 too. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When I try this in SWI-Prolog, I get a false in the second case.

Comment: It is because of the name of the atoms, and I have correct it. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Its because both of your functions are same and i think prolog checks both....in first case it fails because only one of the function satisfies it i.e. path(c,b,P) but in second case
   path(c,b,[c,b]

It check both the functions

```
path(X,Y,[X|P] here X = c and P = b
and
path(X,Y,[X,Y]) here also X=c and Y = b
```

so as both the functions act same in the second case you need to modify one of your cases.
for eg: for 2 vertices only you could use

```
path(X,Y,[X|Y|[]]):- edge(X,Y).
```

instead of

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y]):-
edge(X,Y).
```

it will expect only two variables and i think this should solve your problem.